# Package installed but not working

Tags: packages

I installed the MacTEX package, and want to use the listings package for pretty printing code. According to the TeX Live Utility, the package is installed (I tried re-installing it as well). However, when I try typesetting via TeXShop, I get an error:

```
l.4 \usepackage
             {listings}
?
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

EDIT: Complete document code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
\begin{document}
\author{--}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{--}
\maketitle
\section{1}
Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @JuriRobl Sure! Edited now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The error message is before the `l.4` line and starts with `!`; can you show it?

Comment: You can't use `\usepackage` after `\begin{document}`, move it befor it.

Comment: @JuriRobl Oh, wow! That was it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I didn't find anything with a !
Here's a picture: http://i.imgur.com/V8Cd5k7.png
Anyway, it's resolved now.

Comment: "Can be used only in preamble" would be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler often tries to give you a hint what you can do to fix it.
Sometimes it's very cryptic and involves wizards (If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.), in this case it's just

> LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble

which basically means you can't use it in your document part (after `\begin{document}`), but before it. That's your preamble, and is the only place where you can use some commands like `\usepackage`.